# Import picture and save to isolated storage WP7

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7, storage

I am currently working on a project where the user needs to select a image from there photo gallery and import it. Using the following code I am able to import the picture but I have a few questions.

1. What is the image named upon import?
2. Where is the image located once imported
3. Is it possible to save that image and reload it when the app is opened again (ie using isolated storage)

Heres the code from a tutorial

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace PhoneApp4
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        PhotoChooserTask selectphoto = null;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            selectphoto = new PhotoChooserTask();
            selectphoto.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(selectphoto_Completed);
            selectphoto.Show();

        }

        void selectphoto_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
        {
            if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
            {

                BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(e.ChosenPhoto);
                image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(e.OriginalFileName));

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The PhotoResult contains OriginalFileName.
2. When the PhotoChoserTask completes PhotoResult.ChosenPhoto gives you a stream to the data for the photo.
3. Yes at that point you can store the image in isolated storage.

   ```
     private void Pick_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
          var pc = new PhotoChooserTask();
          pc.Completed += pc_Completed;
          pc.Show();
     } 

       void pc_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
       {
           var originalFilename = Path.GetFileName(e.OriginalFileName);
           SaveImage(e.ChosenPhoto, originalFilename, 0, 100);
       }

       public static void SaveImage(Stream imageStream, string fileName, int orientation, int quality)
       {
           using (var isolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
           {
               if (isolatedStorage.FileExists(fileName))
                   isolatedStorage.DeleteFile(fileName);

               var fileStream = isolatedStorage.CreateFile(fileName);
               var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
               bitmap.SetSource(imageStream);

               var wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);
               wb.SaveJpeg(fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, orientation, quality);
               fileStream.Close();
           }
       }
   ```

Comment: How do i access that file name? And also how would i go about storing it? Do you happen to have a tutorial or a reference you'd suggest?

Comment: Okay sorry for asking more questions but how do i access the file name and if i put the SaveImage code under the onexit class will it save? Thanks so much

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: How do i call that picture when i want to load it?

Comment: string[] filesInTheRoot = store.GetFileNames();