# Need to bind ISO Stores file in a ListBox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listbox

I am trying to store some soundclips which are tagged with Images chosen from ISO Storage through a PhotoChooserTask.
I can successfully display the image in a standalone Image box but when I am setting the Imagebox source inside a listbox It does not shows the image.
Currently what I am doing is something like this:

```
public ImageSource Image
    {

        get {
            try
            {

                BitmapImage image;
                if(Category == 11)
                {
                 image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(this.ImageLocation));
                }

                return image;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                return null;
            }

        }
```

I don't understand what is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BitmapImage` can't load image from `Isolated Storage`. You need to read file image manually

```
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();

        using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(this.ImageLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                bi.SetSource(fileStream);
            }
        }
        return bi;
```

Also, if this won't work, check `CreateOptions` and set it to `None`

Comment: What is the error? Does the file is really saved here? You can use `Windows Phone Power Tools` to be sure that it here and doesn't corrupted

Comment: I have tried this way but i am having an error "Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream." while executing isoStore.OpenFile(this.ImageLocation, FileMode.Open), the value of the file location is "\\Applications\\Data\\A7C5852D-9DD5-4B60-B2EA-8904E0F164FB\\Data\\PlatformData\\PhotoChooser-9b8122a0-c3bb-4095-be4d-4f435dce6211.jpg"

Comment: I am using PhotoChooserTask so the file is already in the storage

Comment: `PhotoChooserTask` does not automatically save image to `Isolated Storage`. To save, look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615095/import-picture-and-save-to-isolated-storage-wp7

Comment: Do I have to copy the images to the apps storage folder?